# web server (iis) role configuration error Sharepoint 2016 in Windos Server 2016

Tags: sharepoint-server, windows-server

I´m trying to install Sharepoint Server 2016 in Windows Server 2016, but the error I show in the image is happening. Does anybody know why?[image]

Comment: in english will be easier for everybody

Comment: Firstly, please, could you try to rewrite the title making a question instead? Regarding the issue, did you try to install the web server role by yourself? Try it and see if you have the same issue. If you install it successfully, try to install again SharePoint 2016.

Comment: Yes, I´ve done it, but it doesn´t work

Comment: Please, view this answer in this post: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/289370/unable-to-process-sharepoint-server-2013-setup-even-though-all-prerequisites-ha/289384#289384

Answer (score 2):

This is known problem. Win Server 2016 is missing some features. You need to ensure they are available.

Run This

```
 Import-Module ServerManager

Add-WindowsFeature Net-Framework-Features,Web-Server,Web-WebServer,Web-Common-Http,Web-Static-Content,Web-Default-Doc,Web-Dir-Browsing,Web-Http-Errors,Web-App-Dev,Web-Asp-Net,Web-Net-Ext,Web-ISAPI-Ext,Web-ISAPI-Filter,Web-Health,Web-Http-Logging,Web-Log-Libraries,Web-Request-Monitor,Web-Http-Tracing,Web-Security,Web-Basic-Auth,Web-Windows-Auth,Web-Filtering,Web-Digest-Auth,Web-Performance,Web-Stat-Compression,Web-Dyn-Compression,Web-Mgmt-Tools,Web-Mgmt-Console,Web-Mgmt-Compat,Web-Metabase,WAS,WAS-Process-Model,WAS-NET-Environment,WAS-Config-APIs,Web-Lgcy-Scripting,Windows-Identity-Foundation,Server-Media-Foundation,Xps-Viewer –Source D:\sources\sxs
```

remember to change this part "–Source D:\sources\sxs" to the drive you have win2016 installation DVD or folder where you extracted sxs from DVD.

More info
https://absolute-sharepoint.com/2017/08/the-tool-was-unable-to-install-web-server-iis-role-sharepoint-2016-on-windows-server-2016.html

I am not sure does it apply to 2016 but on 2012 R2 I faced as well this issue:
I was unable to install .net 3.5 due to certain security updates. After removing those I was able to install.

wusa /uninstall /kb:2966828 /quiet /norestart
Get-WinEvent -MaxEvents 3 -LogName Setup | Select -Expand Message

wusa /uninstall /kb:2966827 /quiet /norestart
Get-WinEvent -MaxEvents 3 -LogName Setup | Select -Expand Message

Remember to re-install those after you complete the installation of SP.

Comment: thank you , but I can´t find the source\sxs on my computer

Comment: I am using windows server 2016 in a virtual machine

Comment: It is on install DVD of the Windows Server. You need to mount it to your vm.

Comment: OK,I´ve done it, but it has returned an Error:0x80073701

Comment: You need to run it one by one to determine on which feature it fails. ie 'Add-WindowsFeature Net-Framework-Features Web-Server –Source D:\sources\sxs' or  Run Get-WindowsFeature to see which one is missing. Then run the command against that specific feature. I expanded my answer with another case (but this one i faced for WS 2012 R2)

Comment: The problem is Windows-Identity-Foundation, the rest of features are installed correctly

Comment: Do you know why? It has returned an Error:0x80073701 when i try to install Windows-Identity-Foundation

Comment: There could be multiple reasons for that to occur. Some issues are caused by language packs some by other cases. Have a look at those threads may be of help: https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/1974434-server-2016-unable-to-add-roles-or-features-after-making-server-a-domain-control ;

Answer (score 0):

In my case this problem was related with disabled Windows Update service. As soon as I started it, configuration of IIS succeeded.

Answer (score 0):

Start Windows Update service before running prerequisiteinstaller. You will not face IIS and AppFabric errors.