# Unable to process SharePoint Server 2013 Setup, even though all prerequisites have been installed / enabled

Tags: sharepoint-server, windows-server-2012-r2

I am using Windows Server 2012. When I open "prerequisiteinstaller", all the prerequisites are already installed / activated, but when I open Setup, an error notification appears. Can you help me?
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Which version of .NET are enabled on the server?

Comment: I have enabled .NET Framework feature version 3.5 and 4.5

Comment: Sorry for classic, silly and annoying question: have you restarted the machine before trying to install SharePoint?

Comment: of course sir..

Comment: Did you run the pre-req installer as admin?

Comment: Yes sir. After i check installation log, i have some error:

Comment: Update to machine.config failed.
Update to DistributedCacheService.exe.config failed.
Windows Server Features or Role Services check failed.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, check if the server has connected to Internet. After, please, (1)restart the server and (2)re-execute the prereq again and do the steps (1) and (2) until you change this status. If that doesn't work, go to the command line (Powershell) with Admin privileges and execute this cdmlets bellow:

```
Import-Module ServerManager

Add-WindowsFeature Net-Framework-Features,Web-Server,Web-WebServer,Web-Common-Http,Web-Static-Content,Web-Default-Doc,Web-Dir-Browsing,Web-Http-Errors,Web-App-Dev,Web-Asp-Net,Web-Net-Ext,Web-ISAPI-Ext,Web-ISAPI-Filter,Web-Health,Web-Http-Logging,Web-Log-Libraries,Web-Request-Monitor,Web-Http-Tracing,Web-Security,Web-Basic-Auth,Web-Windows-Auth,Web-Filtering,Web-Digest-Auth,Web-Performance,Web-Stat-Compression,Web-Dyn-Compression,Web-Mgmt-Tools,Web-Mgmt-Console,Web-Mgmt-Compat,Web-Metabase,Application-Server,AS-Web-Support,AS-TCP-Port-Sharing,AS-WAS-Support, AS-HTTP-Activation,AS-TCP-Activation,AS-Named-Pipes,AS-Net-Framework,WAS,WAS-Process-Model,WAS-NET-Environment,WAS-Config-APIs,Web-Lgcy-Scripting,Windows-Identity-Foundation,Server-Media-Foundation,Xps-Viewer –Source D:\sources\sxs
```

The last parameter "-Source" indicates the drive letter with the Windows Server 2012 media installation (USB or DVD); at least Windows Server 2012, to install new resources to Windows Server, requires the Media Installation.

Comment: It looks like I've done all of these steps before, but it's still not working. Monday, I'll try again and I'll let you know whether it worked or not. Thank you sir.

Comment: @HanifMaliki, is it solution works?